# VBA find text string in a cell and paste it in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a report with text strings with a general date. I'm trying to grab these dates and put them in a cell next to them. How can I do this?

Example:

```
Column N
blah blah blah (Q4 2019)
blah blah (Q3 2019) - Blah
```

```
Column O
Q4 2019
Q3 2019
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data starts in cell `N2` and there is only one bracket in your Strings and all dates are 7 characters in length you could use the following formula in `O2` to get what you want

```
=MID(N2,FIND("(",N2)+1,7)
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
Sub Find_Paste( _
        s As String, _
        cell As Range, _
        column_Offset As Long)
    With cell
        If InStr(.Value, s) > 0 Then .Offset(0, column_Offset) = s
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't extract any substring like the question is asking

Comment: Question was: "VBA find text string in a cell and paste it in another cell"